# how can extension call function in viewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

func1 , which is in an extension is not able to access func2 which is in a viewController. is there a way to make this possible ?

```
func func2() {
   // do something
}

}  //<-- View controller ends here

extension UIViewController {


func func1(){
    func2()
}
```

Comment: Are but functions declared in the same file? Are both part of the same class?

Comment: declared in the same file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have a mistake or typo, you are extending `UIViewController` not `ViewController`, check if you meant this, it works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func func2() {
        print("I am being called")
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    func func1(){
        func2()
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.func1() // Outputs "I am being called"
```

**Example 2** (extension of `UIViewController`):

```
extension UIViewController {
    func func1(){
        if let viewController = self as? ViewController {
            viewController.func2()
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let vc = ViewController()
vc.func1() // Outputs "I am being called"
```

Comment: I dont think there is need of creating object of `ViewController`. you can call it directly by self.

Comment: @dahiya_boy using **Example 2** you cannot call `self.func2()` directly, `UIViewController` does not have such method, and if you do, you will see error `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'func2'`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the method of a `UIViewController` subclass in a `UIViewController` extension which is logical. Since `func2` is a method of your custom view controller, I guess it is a `ViewController` instance.

You should extend `ViewController` but not `UIViewController`.

But if your goal is to extend `UIViewController` it won't be possible.

Hope it helps.

UPDATE: thanks to @Cristik: you can actually use the method from extension this way:

`(self as? ViewController)?.func2()`

UPDATE2:

Here is the code:

[image]

Be aware that `func1` will work **ONLY** for your `MyCustomViewController` cuz only `MyCustomViewController` has that `func2` method.

Sorry for the screenshot it was doing something strange with formatting.

Comment: It would be possible from within a `UIViewController`: `(self as? ViewController)?.func2()`

Comment: when you say extend ViewController, do you mean the name of the class which func2 is located in ?

Comment: Cristik, i need more detail because I am new to swift/ios, can you please explain

Comment: @fredshmed exactly! sorry wasn't sure what's the name of that VC so I assumed it's just `ViewController`